# Multiple row print in table

Tags: codeigniter

I want to print multiple data from the database in one table, however, it shows one row.

Model code is below. Please look at my codes and give some suggestion on how I can solve this issue.

### Model CODE

```
 function show_list()
 {
     $query=$this->db->get('student');
      return $query;
 }
```

Here is my controller code below:

---

### Controller Code

```
<?php
class Showlist extends CI_Controller {
    function index()
    {
        //$this->load->view('showlist');
         $this->load->model('main_model');
        $data['no']=$this->main_model->show_list();  
         //return the data in view  
         $this->load->view('showlist', $data);
    }

}

?>
```

Here is my view code below:

### View Code

```
 <style>

    table 
    {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table, th, td 
    {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
<body>
<html>
<center>
<table>


        <tr>

            <th>NAME </th>
            <th>Student ID</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Fathers Name</th>
            <th>Mothers Name</th>
            <th>Education</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        if($no->num_rows()> 0){
           foreach ($no->result() as $row) {
            ?>
            <tr>

                <td><?php echo $row->Name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->StudentID; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->Address; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->FatherName; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->MotherName; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->Eduation; ?></td>
               <!-- <td><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row["ID"]; ?>">EDIT</a></td>
                <td><a href="delete.php?id1=<?php echo $row["ID"]; ?> "onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete??');">Delete</a></td>-->

            </tr>


            <?php
        }


        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><center><a href='add_new_student.php'>ADD NEW STUDENT</a></center></td>
            <td><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></center></td>
        </tr>

   <?php
        }
         else
   {
           echo 'NO data Found';
   }
   ?>
</table> 

</center>



</html>

</body>
```

It only prints one row:

[image]

There are more data in my database. I try `result()` but it is not printing the rows that I want.

[THis is my table data 4 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hel9r.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

result() display only one row:

Add this line in model code:

```
return $query->result_array();
```

And change the foreach loop :

```
 foreach ($no as $row) {..}
```

Change the line to all the rows:

```
 <td><?php echo $row->Name; ?></td> to
<td><?=$row['Name'];?><td>
```